# React router not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I know this has been asked before but none of the answers applied to me so here goes. I have this basic route setup:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory  } from 'react-router'

import CoreLayout from 'layouts/CoreLayout/CoreLayout'
import AuthLayout from 'layouts/AuthLayout/AuthLayout'
import HomeView from 'views/Home/HomeView'
import AuthView from 'views/Auth/AuthView'
import SignupView from 'views/Signup/SignupView'

export default ( store ) => (
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path='/' component={CoreLayout}>
            <IndexRoute component={HomeView}/>
        </Route>

        <Route component={AuthLayout}>
            <Route path="/signup" component={SignupView} />
            <Route path="/auth" component={AuthView} />
        </Route>
    </Router>
)
```

I also have a button that, when pushed, should redirect to another page `browserHistory.push( '/signup' )`. When clicked, I can see the url updating in the browser but the component is not mounting. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

As requested, here's my `AuthLayout`:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import 'styles/core.scss'

function AuthLayout( { children } ) {
    return (
        <div className='page-container'>
            {children}
        </div>
    )
}

AuthLayout.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.element
};

export default AuthLayout
```

Comment: Can you show as your `AuthLayout` component?

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Is there any output in your browser's JS console?

Comment: No output. I can see the url updating and, if i refresh the browser the app will switch to the new url showing the right component but the console is clear..

Comment: Can you try to change the order like this
`<Route component={AuthLayout}>
...
<Route path='/' component={CoreLayout}>`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean I'm afraid.